# custom Holo theme for tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-2.3-gingerbread

i am trying to create a tab as following which is a Holo  Light theme but as i am using android 2.3.6 i got to create it on my own.

[image]

the problem i am facing is i am bot be able to create the blue bottom like 
here is the code so far in a drawable , **can any one tell me how to create the bottom border for the same ?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="63dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#898989" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="63dp" android:bottom="3px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@color/app_background" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="@dimen/tab_space" android:right="@dimen/tab_space"> 
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">           

            <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#d9d9d9"
                android:endColor="#dfdfdf"/>        

            <!-- this is create a border but on every side -->
            <stroke android:width="3px" android:color="#38c0f4" />



        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

so wht i dont know is to create

```
1) bottom stroke 
2) shadow under each tab
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just set a 9 patch image as the background image. And this image could contain a stroke.

Answer (score -1):

Even if this is not totally on topic of your question, I suggest to migrate your project to [ActionBarSherlock](http://www.actionbarsherlock.com/). ActionBarSherlock lets you use all the ICS Actionbar Apis with earlier API-Levels and brings the ICS Actionbar Style to all Devices with at least Android 2.2.

Using this project will make it very easy to move your app to Ice Cream Sandwich compatibility, and solve your current design problem.

Comment: The only problem with this library is its unnecessary bulking up my application

Comment: It will take up somewhat around 400kb. But it will save a lot of time and a lot of code that you have to write and maintain.

Comment: Honestly , the problem is i have almost finished the application and i have used android compatibility library only, so now i got to spend more time to integrate above library in my tab :)